# How to graph a linear regression in python through sklearn code and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

My code its pretty straightfoward, I don´t have ideas of how to do the graphic of the linear regression.

```
X = data[featured_cols]
Y = data["Total Spend"]
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X , Y)

data["Total Spend Prediction"] = lm.predict(pd.DataFrame(data[featured_cols]))
```

I´d tried with this:

```
y_pred = data["Total Spend Prediction"]
plt.plot(X, Y, "ro")
plt.plot(X, y_pred, "ro")
```

but i got an error that said: "X, and Y should be of the same size"

Comment: You should plot one column values of the dataframe versus another. But X here is a dataframe of multiple columns while Y is a series

Answer (score 0):

So I've tested your code with my own data, and couldn't reproduce the error. My best advice would be to check your version of matplotlib, because for me plt.plot works fine with multiple columns as X or Y, but perhaps older matplotlib doesn't work that way.